# How can I build something like this using Highcharts?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highcharts

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/kUE7z/

Instead I want to use JSON to pull category names instead of a tsv like that example.
My category data for the x-axis are job numbers in this format, [1,2,3,4,5].

Here's what my php looks like.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM view_percentof_budgeted 
        WHERE PercentofBudgetedHrs IS NOT NULL ";

    $result = mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $jobNum[] = $row['Job_Num'];
    $jobData[$row['Job_Num']] = $row['PercentofBudgetedHrs'];
    $jobDrillData[$row['Job_Num']][] = $row;
}


 print json_encode($jobNum, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); //Job num data
```

I don't understand where I would plug this data if I'm using that example. I want it to drill down the same way and have the second level of the drilldown with another list of categories and their own percentages which add up to the total of the job number percentage in level 1.

What mine would look like: http://jsfiddle.net/98Fuq/4/

Comment: first you need to have the hierarchical data to be available as given in the example

Comment: You need prepare the same structure in php by arrays and pushing correct parameters, then transform to JSON.